# Integrate chrome extensions with phantomjs

Tags: google-chrome-extension, phantomjs, adblock

Is there a way we can install chrome extensions (.crx) with phantomjs?

My task here is to integrate [adblockplus](https://adblockplus.org/en/chrome) with phantomjs so that I can filter all the ad-urls and report using phantomjs.

Or any other way to integrate the [adblockplus](https://adblockplus.org/en/chrome) extension with phantomjs?

Comment: Yes. So what have you tried that didnt work?

Comment: @ZigMandel I hav the code for adblockplus. I am not sure what is its entry point and where does it fit into PhantomJs so that it starts working. Ideally, it should be active before `page.open`. I can tweek the extension and append it in `onResourceRequested` callback. Wanted to know if there is any other way

Comment: Do you have an update or even an answer?

Comment: @ArtjomB.- There doesn't seem to be any way to integrate the whole extension. I instead had to implement the part of adblockplus logic into phantomjs which I required.

Comment: Want exactly the same for a 'automated content extraction algorithm'. Did you found any solution?

Comment: @FrankRoth: Sadly, no. I extracted parts of what I wanted and re-wrote them in phantom.

Comment: @Devaroop, do you still have that code? Can you share it? How complicated is it to implement? Thanks

Comment: @BogdanPăun None yet, I have moved away from it now.

Answer (score 3):

PhantomJS is based on a three-year old WebKit fork (QtWebKit), not Chromium. Therefore you cannot load Chrome extensions in PhantomJS.

If you want to use Chrome extensions in an automated way, I suggest to use the [ChromeDriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) from the Selenium WebDriver project.