# How Can I Add PhantomJS to My Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, phantomjs

I need to scrape (public) HTML Data after the JavaScript on the page has loaded. After doing some research, I found that PhantomJS can be useful in accomplishing this task. However, while I can add PhantomJS to my local computer, I don't know how to add it to my chrome extension. Does anybody know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrate chrome extensions with phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603708/integrate-chrome-extensions-with-phantomjs)

Comment: I also think using PhantomJS for some probably simple scraping is quite an overkill.

Comment: @PredatorIWD Is there another (perhaps simpler) way to scrape data generated by JavaScript? I was using the Fetch API before but it only returns the raw HTML (before the JavaScript on the page is loaded).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. PhantomJS is a web browser, not a Javascript library.

**Alternative 1. Scrape from the Chrome Extension**

You can use the chrome extension APIs to do the following:

1. Create a tab containing the page you want to scrape
2. Load a content script into the tab that:

   1. Waits for the page to finish loading
   2. Scrapes the data you want
   3. Messages the scraped data to wherever you need it
3. Close the tab

**Alternative 2. Scrape with a Headless Browser Running on Your Own Server**

Use Google's own headless Chrome library [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to scrape the data you want. An easy way to get started for free is with a [Google App Engine Standard Tier NodeJS instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-headless-chrome-with-puppeteer).